How to use build number as part of INF driverVer
I am a beginner working on INF files.
My .vcxproj file is having a property that uses 1.0.14.0 to use it in driverVer . My INF driverVer as follows DriverVer=04/10/2024,10.0.14.0
I would like to use build number in my INF file ,something like 1.0.14.$(build number).
How can I use azure build number to stamp my INF file ?
I tried using environment variable . But , the driverVer doesn’t pick the build number .

Based on your post's tags, I'll assume your build agent is Windows based.
You can achieve the desired result by using a PowerShell Script Task just after your Get Sources step in your pipeline.
You could use this script:
# Get the build number from environment variable or build system
$buildNumber = $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER

# Path to driverVer.inf file (update this path if required
$infFilePath = "./driverVer.inf"

# Read the content of the file
$content = Get-Content -Path $infFilePath

# Define the regex pattern to capture only the final digit of the version number. Using capture groups
$pattern = '(DriverVer=\d+/\d+/\d+,\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.)(\d+)'

# Replace the final digit with the buildNumber using the regex pattern
$newContent = $content -replace $pattern, $1 + $buildNumber

# Write the updated content back to the file
Set-Content -Path $infFilePath -Value $newContent


You can use the replace token task to replace the DriverVer with the build number in your azure DevOps pipeline.
My test Steps:

Install the extension to the organization.
Use the #{Build.BuildNumber}# pattern in the driverVer.inf in the repo:

[Version]
DriverVer=1.0.14.#{Build.BuildNumber}#


Use the following yaml to customize the build numbers. This is to make the variable $(Build.BuildNumber) only contains a single version number instead of the default Date + version number. Then use the replace token task to replace the #{Build.BuildNumber}# to the actual build number in the inf file.

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

name: $(Rev:r)

steps:
- script: echo '$(Build.BuildNumber)' # outputs customized build number

- task: replacetokens@6
  inputs:
    sources: '*.inf'


When the build number is 7, the replaced driverVer.inf looks like the following one.

[Version]
DriverVer=1.0.14.7

